Raydium swap: Program log: Error: Invalid Sign Account
Just created instruction to swap on raydium v4 in golang and when i try to send the transaction, have this error:
Program log: Error: Invalid Sign Account
checked my public and private key and are correct.
After many research online, i didnt found a response.

Would be helpful if you can share some more context. Try giving a code sample or a solscan link.
